# Qt executable does not exist in Cmake project

Tags: qt, debugging, ubuntu-14.04

I have a cmake project opened in `Qt5.2.1` under `Ubuntu 14.04`. 
In `project->build->CMake arguments: -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:=Debug`

After I build successfully the project and try to run it, I get the following error in the Application Output:
`Executable /home/../foo does not exist.`
If I try to debug the application, a popup window error is:

`Starting executable failed:
/home/../foo: No such file or directory.`

The executable is built but the name is actually `food` and not `foo`. So, it is obvious why the run and debug can't find the executable. I'm new with Qt. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two solutions:

1. in Project->Run Add new executable. If `foo` was the first, then for debug add a new executable, it will be called `foo2` and this will be pointing to the good executable `food`.
2. install `Qt5.7` with `Qt-creator 4.0.2` - everything works out of the box

I prefer the second.

Answer (score 9):

Go to Project->Run and from "Run configuration" button group select "Add" combo box. Then select "Custom Executable".

Then Browse and select path to executable.

I'm using Qt 5.9.